# How to add custom taxonomies to the meta fields in yoast SEO?

Tags: wordpress, seo, custom-post-type, meta

I have a wordpress 4.2.1 based website with Yoast wordpress SEO plugin. In this site I have several custom posts types such as "publications" with some custom taxonomies "keywords, authors" all are made by custom post type UI plugin.
When viewing the page source of articles published in that custom post type the code shows meta properties like:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="bla bla bla- Marketing" />
<meta property="og:description" content="bla bla bla" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Marketing" />
```

Please, how do I make a Yoast SEO plugin show meta properties of custom taxonomies related to such post type?

Comment: actually i need it to show this: <meta property="og:keywords" content="bla, bla, bla" />
<meta property="og:authors" content="author1, author2" />

Answer (score 0):

well you can use wordpress functions to populate this data. but it should be within the wordpress loop.

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?> 
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo get_the_title();?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
```

Comment: thanks, but i need them to be within the loop please. also, the purpose is to show the custom taxonomies not only the general meta title or site name

Comment: ok this shows the meta of title, description and site name. but it doesn't show the meta of the custom taxonomies :(

Comment: Well then you will have to add conditions to it, so if its a category then it should echo the title of the category instead of the page title etc.